# List of New Metasploit Modules

Tags: metasploit

I would think that this would be an easy thing to find, but it there a running list that someone maintains that shows new Metasploit modules as they are released?  One thing that I do is keep an eye on the Metasploit Framework page on GitHub, which is useful, but not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: why isn't githib what you want? you get rss updates when things happen, and the updates and changes are timestamped

Comment: the official page is sorted by release date: https://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/

Comment: rapid7.com/db/modules works good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i*s* there a running list that someone maintains that shows new Metasploit modules as they are released?

For that i think you want something like [**https://www.exploit-db.com/**](https://www.exploit-db.com/),

This will have a very up-to-date view of exploits recently made public, sorted by type.

New Metasploit modules will be in there as well, but that's just a small part of the exploits that are publicly released. Also using these will make the step from using just msfconsole to finding security holes yourself easier.

As mentioned, https://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/ Will have a comprehensive list of all previously released modules.